# My terminal is pure white // removal of the things spf13 has done to my Ubuntu

Tags: bash, vim, bashrc

I have installed spf13 by using the command:

```
curl http://j.mp/spf13-vim3 -L -o - | sh
```

I didn't liked what I got, so I tried to get rid of it. I managed to get to my previous VIM configuration, but now I have no colours in my terminal. I would like to get rid of everything the instalation of spf13-vim has done to me. Can anyone help me?

Comment: In your terminal in general or only Vim? Because that script only touches vim-related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I quick search found these resources:

- [How to uninstall](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim/issues/57)
- [How to uninstall spf13 vim distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124483/how-to-uninstall-spf13-vim-distribution)

If you have saved your own configuration, it should be enough to remove the following files and directories, and restore your own, pre-spf13 configuration:

```
~/.vimrc
~/.gvimrc
~/.vim/
```